# Python Flask на своем ПК

Tags: python, flask

Как я могу получить доступ с своему приложению через wan-ip(ip выданный провайдером).
На 127.0.0.1:5000 работает, но мне нужно получить доступ через интернет.

Comment: плюс достаточно широкий вопрос, включающий много тем для обсуждения

Comment: У вас может быть и не настоящий внешний адрес, вопрос реально непростой.